# Rover 25 Head Gasket replacement - is it a long-term fix?

Tags: head-gasket

My Rover 25 (2004, <50k) began overheating and the nearest-to-me-at-the-time garage (not my usual one) which I pulled in to diagnosed head gasket failure. They gave a £700 estimate for a new head gasket, skimming, and a big list of parts that 'should always be replaced at the same time', they said.

- Is head gasket replacement a long-term fix in people's experience, or is it likely to recur again soon?
- Does this sound reasonable for the repairs?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done properly, a head gasket replacement should be a long-term fix. The K series had a reputation for fragile head gaskets, but this was improved with a change to the design - I think this came in around 2001, so yours should have it. There is also a subsequent change to the head gasket design introduced by Land Rover for the Freelander (which uses the same engine), that should be used when replacing a K-series head gasket, and makes the engine a lot stronger.

That sounds rather expensive to me though, I'd expect it to be around the £400 mark - what things were included on that list? It is worth talking to a Rover or Land Rover specialist if you have one nearby - What part of the country are you in?

Comment: Thanks - useful info!. I'm in NE England, Northumberland-ish.

Comment: Ah - I don't know any specialists up there, only in the SE...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean they wanted to change the timing belt, waterpump, auxiliary belt, head bolts, etc, then yes, it sounds about right. I don't live in Britain, but GBP700 is somewhere in the middle of what I paid for a headgasket job for my Astra Coupe (GBP500) and Subaru Forester (GBP1100), so it's not outlandish.

Some garages might elect to re-use most of the components if they look to be in good order, some others replace them as a matter of course. Best thing is to ask them.